# registration document recognition and technical inspection report France

Tags: tesseract, ppp

I use Tesseract for document recognition:
Gray card
Technical inspection (Report) France
It works well, I had to cut the captures into portions to clearly differentiate the recognition blocks otherwise the texts were mixed.
However it works fine if my Windows 10 or 11 desktop scale is at 100%
However, if the scale is greater than 100%, for example 200% (high definition laptop PC) the recognition no longer works?
Is there a simple way to make the recognition work regardless of the Windows desktop scaling (DPI) setting?
Thank you for your advice

I'am French escuse my english

To choose the portions of images to read, I tried to change the image resolution by calculating the DPI according to the desktop scale but that doesn't change anything.
example
Bitmap.setResolution(HorizontalResolution/dpiScaleX, VerticalResolution/dpiScaleY)
DpiScale obtained by using a DPIHelper class (found on the net)